# Implementing a collaborative text editor using nodejs/react/socket but encountering problems because of slow heroku servers

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, heroku, socket.io

I've tried making a collaborative editor using socket.io with reactjs frontend and node backend. Here's the piece of logic which I think is causing problems....

When a client starts typing on the editor, I've used onInput event to emit a socket response say "typing" which carries the complete text on the editor inside data object at the moment client presses a key. Now server catches this typing event and in response to that, emits another socket response called "typed" which contains the same data but the server sends this response to all the clients connected to the server.... Now all clients receive this event inside componentDidMount and then update the state variable "codeValue" which updates the editor content for all the clients.

There are two problems, first one that on one single typing event, server is emitting numerous typed events ( it happens only in heroku server and not on local host ) and the other problem is that heroku servers are slow and before the server sends response to update the state of clients, clients had already entered more text on the editor which simply vanishes when the state is updated.....

FRONTEND CODE:

```
import React from "react";
import { Dropdown } from "semantic-ui-react";
import languages from "../utils/languages";
//Styles

import "../styles/app.css";

//Editor
 import * as ace from "ace-builds";
//  import SocketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-c_cpp";
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-github";
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/ext-language_tools";
import AceEditor from "react-ace";

let check = true;
let ld;

//  const endpoint = "http://localhost:4676";
//  const socket = SocketIOClient(endpoint, { transports: ["websocket"] });

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      codeValue: languages[0].template,
      currentLang: languages[0].key,
    };
    this.codeEditor = React.createRef();
    this.fireTyping = this.fireTyping.bind(this);
    this.onDDChange = this.onDDChange.bind(this);
    this.runCode = this.runCode.bind(this);
    this.handleOutput = this.handleOutput.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      this.props.socket.on("typed", (data) => {
        console.log(35, data.text)
        this.setState({
          codeValue: data.text,
        });
        check = true;
        console.log(check)
      });
    
    this.props.socket.on('ans',(data) => {
      console.log(data.output)
      //handleOutput(data.output)

  })
  }

  fireTyping = () => {
    ld = this.codeEditor.current.editor.getValue()
    //console.log(ld)
    if(check) {
      console.log(48, this.codeEditor.current.editor.getValue(), check);
      this.props.socket.emit("typing", {
        text: ld,
      });
      check = false;
    }
    console.log(check)
  };

  onDDChange = (e, data) => {
    const selectedVal = languages.filter((v) => v.key == data.value)
    this.setState({currentLang : data.value, codeValue: selectedVal[0].template})
  }

  runCode = () => {
    this.props.socket.emit('run', {
      code: this.codeEditor.current.editor.getValue(),
      lang: this.state.currentLang,
      input: ''
  })
  }

  handleOutput = () => {

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Dropdown
          placeholder="Languages"
          onChange = {this.onDDChange}
          selection
          value = {this.state.currentLang}
          options={languages}
        />

        <AceEditor
          style={{
            margin: "3rem auto",
            width: "80vw",
            height: "70vh",
          }}
          fontSize={18}
          ref={this.codeEditor}
          mode="c_cpp"
          theme="github"
          value={this.state.codeValue}
          onInput={this.fireTyping}
          showPrintMargin={false}
          name="UNIQUE_ID_OF_DIV"
          editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
          setOptions={{
            
            enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
            enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
            enableSnippets: true,
          }}
        />
        <div className="container">
          <button
            onClick={this.runCode}
            style={{
              marginLeft: "40rem",
            }}
            className="large ui teal button"
          >
            Run
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

BACKEND CODE:

```
const express = require("express");
const request = require("request");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(app);
const path = require('path')
const socket = require("socket.io");
const io = socket(server);

const port = process.env.PORT || 4676

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')))

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client/build/index.html'))
})

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  let previousCode, currentCode;
  console.log(socket.id);
  socket.on("typing", (data) => {
    currentCode = data.text
    console.log('typing')
    console.log(previousCode === currentCode)
    if(previousCode !== currentCode){
      console.log(1)
      io.emit("typed", data);
      previousCode = currentCode;
      currentCode = ''
    }
  });
});

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("server started at http://localhost:4676");
});
```

I've spent hours trying to fix this but I couldn't.... Any help would be appreciated ☺️

Let me know if you need code reference, I'll share the repository

Comment: App works fine when I type slow ( taking pause of a second or half after entering a character), problem occurs when i type fast

Comment: how did things go?

Comment: Stopped working on this @PeterNoges